# @PostConstruct doesnt work in Play Framework 2.4

Tags: java, playframework

I need to provide some configuration to my bean class. In regular Spring application I'm using @PostConstruct but it not seems to be working in Play 2.4

I use @Singleton annotation on my bean class. I can inject in but @PostConstruct method is ignored. How can I pass additional configuration to my bean?

PS. the method is defined as follows:

```
void init() {
}
```

I've tried make it public\private but nothing helps

Thanks

Comment: By default Spring isn't aware of the `@PostConstruct` annotation. To turn it on you have to either register `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` or specify the `<context:annotation-config />` in your context configuration.

Answer (score 3):

Play and it's default Dependency Injection implementation Guice don't support full component lifecylce management via annotations from `JSR 250: Common Annotations for the Java Platform`. They only implement `JSR 330: Dependency Injection for Java`. However Play has some [limited component lifecycle support](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaDependencyInjection#Component-lifecycle) and offers the possibility to do component cleanup when the play application shuts down.

For your specific requirement to do some initialization tasks for a singleton component I would recommend to use the constructor.
You can even inject other components via constructor injection.

```
@Singleton
public class MyComponent {
    @Inject
    Logger log;

    @Inject
    public MyComponent(MyConfiguration conf) {
        conf.load();
        init();
    }

    public void init(){
        log.info("init");
    }
}
```